# Display two arrays in two columns of a table

Tags: php, arrays, html, html-table

I have two arrays by name

```
$names = array(1A,1B,1C,2A,2B,2C,3A,3B,3C);
    $user_names = array(Jen, Smith, Nick, Rose, Jason, Ralph, Bruce, Linda, Kate);

<table class="stak">
    <?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $i ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $name ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $user_name ?> </td>
        <?php
        $i++;?>
        </tr><?php 
    }
    $j = 1;
    foreach ($user_names as $user_name) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $j ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $user_name ?> </td> 
        <?php
        $j++;?>
        </tr><?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

I want to display them in one table with 3 columns Sl NO, Names, User Names in PHP
Please help.

[image: Result]

Comment: Also your arrays have syntax errors.

Comment: Tried foreach loop but whole thing got messed up.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried, and your desired output? This question is hella unclear...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because you need to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: <table class="stak">
 <?php
 $i = 1;
 foreach ($names as $name) {
  ?>
  <tr>
   <td> <?php echo $i ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $name ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $user_name ?> </td>
  <?php
  $i++;?>
  </tr><?php 
 }

 $j = 1;
 foreach ($user_names as $user_name) {
  ?>
  <tr>
   <td> <?php echo $j ?> </td>
   <td> <?php echo $user_name ?> </td> 
  <?php
  $j++;?>
  </tr><?php
 }
 ?>
</table>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution :**

```
$names = array("1A","1B","1C","2A","2B","2C","3A","3B","3C");
    $user_names = array("Jen", "Smith", "Nick", "Rose", "Jason", "Ralph", "Bruce","Linda", "Kate");

    $combine = array_combine($names, $user_names);



    $html = "<table>";
    $html .= "<tr><td>Sl.No</td><td>Name</td><td>Username</td></tr>";
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($combine as $names =>  $user_names):

        $html .= "<tr>";
        $html .= "<td>".$i."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$names."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$user_names."</td>";
        $html .= "</tr>";

        $i++;
    endforeach;
    $html .= "</table>";

    echo $html;
```

**Output :**

```
Sl.No   Name    Username
1   1A  Jen
2   1B  Smith
3   1C  Nick
4   2A  Rose
5   2B  Jason
6   2C  Ralph
7   3A  Bruce
8   3B  Linda
9   3C  Kate
```

**Second case (In case of more then 2 arrays):**

```
$names = array("1A","1B","1C","2A","2B","2C","3A","3B","3C");
$user_names = array("Jen", "Smith", "Nick", "Rose", "Jason", "Ralph", "Bruce","Linda", "Kate");
$dob = array("12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20");
$height = array("6","7","8","5","4","7","5","9","5");


$html = "<table>";
$html .= "<tr><td>Sl.No</td><td>Name</td><td>Username</td><td>dob</td><td>height</td></tr>";

foreach ($names as $id => $key):

        $html .= "<tr>";
        $html .= "<td>".($id+1)."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$key."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$user_names[$id]."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$dob[$id]."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$height[$id]."</td>";
        $html .= "</tr>";

endforeach;

$html .= "</table>";
echo $html;
```

Comment: How many arrays can I combine like this? Cuz I have 2 more arrays to be displayed in a same table in columns.

Comment: In that case you need to use for loop.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do that,.?

Comment: please tell me your requirement here so that i can send you code

Comment: Their is 2 more arrays as date of birth for all users, and height of all users, They have be 4th and 5th columns, You can take random data for those arrays,.

Comment: code updated, check and let me know if you still have any issue

Comment: It is working awesomely @DeepakMankotia,. Thank you so much,.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works. I tested.

```
$names = array('1A','1B','1C','2A','2B','2C','3A','3B','3C');
$user_names = array('Jen', 'Smith', 'Nick', 'Rose', 'Jason', 'Ralph', 'Bruce', 'Linda', 'Kate');

$size = count($names);

$output = "<table>";
$output .= "<tr><td>Sl.No</td><td>Name</td><td>Username</td></tr>";

for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
    $output .= "<tr>";
    $output .= "<td>".($i+1)."</td>";
    $output .= "<td>".$names[$i]."</td>";
    $output .= "<td>".$user_names[$i]."</td>";
    $output .= "</tr>";
}

$output .= "</table>";

echo $output;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was writing... use a `for` loop to iterate through both arrays simultaneously. Good answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and a fast way to display your datas in a array

```
<?php

// DATAS
$names = array('1A','1B','1C','2A','2B','2C','3A','3B','3C');
$user_names = array('Jen','Smith','Nick','Rose','Jason','Ralph','Bruce','Linda','Kate');

// HTML
$table = '<table><thead><tr>';
$table .= '<th>Name</th><th>User name</th>';
$table .= '</tr></thead><tbody>';

for ($i=0; $i < count($names) ; $i++) {
  $table .= '<tr>';
  $table .= '<td>'.$names[$i].'</td>';
  $table .= '<td>'.$user_names[$i].'</td>';
  $table .= '</tr>';
}

$table .= '</tbody>';

echo $table;
```

Here is the html result

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>User name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>1A</td>
    <td>Jen</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>1B</td>
     <td>Smith</td>
   </tr>
   ...
 </tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kevin,.